# Separating Docker files and application source files to optimize production environment

Tags: docker

I have a bunch of (Ruby) scripts stored on a server. Up until now, my team has used them by opening an accessor app that launches a list of the script names, and they select the script they want to run in that instance on the files in their working folder. The scripts are run directly from the server, so updates made to the script files are automatically reflected when a user runs the script.

The scripts require a fair amount of specific dependencies, so I'm trying to move to a Docker-based workflow to eliminate the problems we encounter with incongruent computer environments. I've been able to successfully build an image with our script library and run an instance of it on my computer.

However, all of the documentation and tutorials include the application source files when building an image, so that all the files are copied over by the Dockerfile. From my understanding, this means that any time the code in the application files needs to be updated, all the users will need to rebuild the image before trying to run anything. I would very rarely ever need to make changes to the environment settings/dependencies, but the app code is changed relatively frequently, so it seems like having every user rebuild an image every single time a line of app code is changed would actually slow down everyone's workflow considerably.

My question is this: Is it not possible to have Docker simply create the *environment* that a user must have to run the applications, but have the applications themselves still run directly off the server where they were originally stored? And does a new container need to be created every single time a user wants to run any one of the scripts? (The users are not tech-savvy.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you'd do this by using a Docker image *instead of* the checked-out tree of scripts.  You can use a Docker *registry* to store a built copy of the image somewhere on the network; Docker Hub works for this, most large public-cloud providers have some version of this (AWS ECR, Google GCR, Azure ACR, ...), or you can run your own.  The workflow for using this would generally look like

```sh
# Get any updates to the "latest" version of the image
# (can be run infrequently)
docker pull ourorg/scripts

# Actually run the script, injecting config files and credentials
docker run --rm \
  -v $PWD/config:/config \
  -v $HOME/.ssh:/config/.ssh \
  ourorg/scripts \
  some_script.rb

# Nothing in this example actually requires a local copy of the scripts
```

I'm envisioning a directory that has kind of a mix of scripts and support files and not a lot of organization to it.  Still, you could write a simple Dockerfile that looks like

```sh
FROM ruby:2.7
WORKDIR /opt/scripts

# As of Bundler 2.1, there is no compatibility between Bundler
# versions; this must match exactly what is in Gemfile.lock
RUN gem install bundler -v 2.1.4

# Copy the scripts in and do basic installation
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock .
RUN bundle install
COPY . .
ENV PATH /opt/scripts:$PATH

# Prefix all commands with...
ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec"]

# The default command to run is...
CMD ["ls"]
```

On the back end you'd need a *continous integration* service (Jenkins is popular if a little unwieldy; there are a large selection of cloud-hosted ones) that can rebuild the Docker image whenever there's a commit to the source repository.  You can generally rig this up so that it happens automatically whenever anybody pushes anything.

This process makes more sense of most people are just using the set of scripts and few of them are developing them.  It's also a little bit difficult to discover what the scripts are (you might be able to `docker run --rm ourorg/scripts ls` though).

> Is it not possible to have Docker simply create the environment that a user must have to run the applications, but have the applications themselves still run directly off the server where they were originally stored?

This always strikes me as an ineffective use of Docker.  You have all of the fiddly steps of your current workflow that require everyone to run a `git pull` or equivalent routinely, but you also have to inject the host source tree into the container.  If there are OS incompatibilities in, for example, native gems in the `vendor` tree, you have to work around that.

```sh
# You still need to do this periodically
git pull

# And you also need to
sudo docker run \
  --rm \
  -v $PWD:/app \
  -v $HOME/config:/config \
  -v $HOME/.ssh:/config/.ssh \
  -w /app \
  ruby:2.7 \
  bundle exec ./some_script.rb
```

Some of these details (especially the config file and credentials) you'd have to deal with even if you did build an image; some others of the details you could improve by building an image.  Inside the image you need to correct the ownership and permissions on the ssh keys and replace the `$PWD/vendor` tree with something the container can run, without modifying the mounted host directories.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm new to Docker and still figuring it out. To clarify re: the last part—only the few developers use git. Once an update is deployed to production, the scripts on the server are updated. Since the users run the scripts off the server, they're already running the most up-to-date versions. This makes everything instantaneous for them (no git pull, no logging in for each execution), which saves a lot of time since they run the scripts so frequently. I was hoping to maintain the same level of time-saving for them but I'm starting to think Docker may not be the solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it not possible to have Docker simply create the environment that a user must have to run the applications, but have the applications themselves still run directly off the server where they were originally stored?

You can build an image with all the environment already installed then mount the directory with the scripts so the container can read the scripts from the host. Something like

```
docker run -it --rm -v /opt/myscripts:/myscripts myimage somescript.rb
```

Then your image Dockerfile would end with:

```
WORKDIR /myscripts
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/ruby"]
```

> And does a new container need to be created every single time a user wants to run any one of the scripts?

Of course, a container is just an isolated process managed by docker, you could make a wrapper so the users wouldn't need to type the full `docker run` command.